# error: package com.google.gson does not exist (in play framwork 2.0)

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am trying to use com.google.gson in my play framework2.0 project, I have included the jar files in libraries, and also mention them in my build.scala file, but it is still giving me the error : `package com.google.gson` does not exist.

My `build.scala` file looks like :

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
                    // Add your project dependencies here,

                    "com.google.gson" % "gson" % "2.2.2"
        )
```

and i have downloaded the jar files from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.2-release.zip&can=2&q)

please suggest should I include the all the three jar files in the `build.scala`? or my build.scala file is correct?

Comment: did you run `play update` and then `play eclipsify` afterwards? (if you use eclipse as your IDE)

Answer (score 1):

You must used :

"com.google**.code.**gson" % "gson" % "2.2.2"

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it one way or the other :

- Include it in the `build.scala` file and let Play download it for you.
- Or include the jar directly in the `lib` folder.

You should do it both ways.

And as was said in adis's comment : if you use an IDE have you reloaded it?